# cakephp access through models

Tags: cakephp, model

I try to code a order system and it is my first cake project.

i have a order, a user and a useraddress.

```
//Order model
public $belongsTo = array(

    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User'
));

//User model
public $hasOne = array(
    'Useradr' => array(
        'className' => 'Useradr',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'order' => ''
   )
);
//maybe not necessary Useradr model

public $belongsTo = 'User';
```

Now i want to access the useraddress while i add/edit a voucher.

I can access the User in the voucher edit view:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('User.email',array(
        'label' => 'Email',
    ));
```

But not the Useraddress. What iam doing wrong ?

Thank you very much!

Julius

Comment: please can you add your query,means "find" statement

Comment: sorry please can you add form->input for Useraddress

Comment: i thought in this direction, but its not working.

$this->set('useradrs', $this->Voucher->User->Useradr->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $userid))));

$this->set(compact('useradrs'));

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('Useradr.city',array('label' => 'City',));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the correct model prefix.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Useradr.some_field',array(
        'label' => 'Some Field',
    ));
```

I suggest you to do the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#build-a-blog) instead of starting blindly coding. Also reading about [the conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) is a good idea.

Further Useradr is a pretty bad name, better would be UserAddress. Abbreviations suck for multiple reason. First they're hard to guess if you don't know what they mean and the inflector very likey does not like them either and might screw up the singular/plural cases. Read [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), very nice book about how to write clean code.

Comment: hi, thank you for your advices. the problem is, that useradr belongs to user. but i want to access it from voucher!

Comment: If your Voucher model isn't connected to the User model, then you just need to `$this->loadModel('Useradr');` in `VouchersController` and access it via `$this->Useradr`.